# Firebase with React - unable to delete items from the database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

Below is my App.js component-

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Cart from './Cart'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import firebase from './firebase'

function App() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    

   useEffect(()=>{
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('products');
    ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
        const data = doc.data();
        items.push(data)
        data['id'] = doc.id
        
      })
      setProducts(items);

    })

   },[]);

    const handleIncreaseQuantity = (product) =>{
          const index = products.indexOf(product)
          products[index].qty += 1; 
          setProducts([...products])
    }

    const handleDecreaseQuantity = (product) =>{
      const index = products.indexOf(product)

      if(products[index].qty > 0){
          products[index].qty -= 1; 
          setProducts([...products])
      }
      
    }

    const handleDeleteQuantity = (product) =>{
        // const productId = product.id
        // const newProducts = products.filter((item) => (item.id !== productId))
        // setProducts([...newProducts])
        // console.log(newProducts)
        // console.log(product.prototype)
        
        firebase.firestore().collection('products').doc(product.id).remove()
          
          console.log(`product id: ${product.id}`)
    }

    const getCartCount = () =>{
      var count = 0;

      products.forEach((item) => ( 
        count += item.qty
      ))

      return count;
    }

    const getCartTotal = () =>{

      var count = 0;
      products.map((product) =>(
        count += product.qty*product.price
        ))
        return count;
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar count = {getCartCount()}/>
      <Cart 
          products = {products}
          onIncreaseQty = {handleIncreaseQuantity}
          onDecreaseQty = {handleDecreaseQuantity}
          onDeleteQty = {handleDeleteQuantity}
      />
      <div className="cart-total">
        TOTAL: {getCartTotal()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want my app to function in a way that whenever I click the delete icon(see the image at the last), the item is deleted from the database. I just don't know how to do it. I am using *.remove()* (see `handleDeleteQuantity()` function) but it's throwing an error that *.remove* is not a function. Or maybe I don't know exactly what code goes in `handleDeleteQuantity()` to remove the item.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Firebase realtime database and Firestore are 2 different databases so make sure you use the correct tag and follow the correct documentation. If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the tick icon and upvote using the upward arrow icon else feel free to ask further queries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.remove()` method is used to delete data from [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). [Firestore's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) says, *"To delete a document, use the delete() method."* Also try awaiting that method in an async function or just handle the promise using `.then` and `.catch`.

```
const handleDeleteQuantity = (product) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('products').doc(product.id).delete().then(() => {
    console.log(`product id: ${product.id}`)
  }).catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
```

> Deleting a document does not delete its subcollections!

Comment: Thank you, it was useful. I just wanted to ask one more thing- is there any other way (from the one which I already used in useEffect()), to associate the firebase generated id to each of the product as their property so that it may define it's uniqueness?

Comment: @SaadAhmad I'm not a React user but passing the document ID in the function is pretty normal or adding the document ID as a property for that `Cart` element.